# Integration of allure in selenium project

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception, allure, reportportal

I am having this error when I am running my selenium test cases

```
 Class `Codeception\Extension\ReportPortal` is not defined. Autoload it or include i   
  nto '_bootstrap.php' file of 'tests' directory
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "8.1.*",
        "php-webdriver/webdriver": "1.14.*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "^1.19",
        "allure-framework/allure-codeception": "^2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/robo-paracept": "^3.1",
        "codeception/codeception": "^5.0",
        "codeception/module-webdriver": "^4.0",
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
    }
}
```

my codeception.yml

```
namespace: Tests
support_namespace: Support
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/Support/Data
    support: tests/Support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

I am using phpstrom so I tried with clearing cache. clone the project again. Try to find reportportal in my whole project but it doesnt exsists.